# Room - Is it possible to use OFFSET and FETCH NEXT in a query?

Tags: android, jquery, sql, database, android-room

I'm trying to implement a pagination build in **Room** database android, and I need to have the clause `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` which is not alowing me to use, what's the way to implement a query using these clauses. Did some research but no results gained. The SQL query I'm trying to implement on ROOM dao looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY id OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I managed to achieve and it's working just fine:

(Kotlin sample)

```sql
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE name LIKE :param LIMIT :pageSize OFFSET :pageIndex
```

---

where:

- PARAM = search criteria,
- PAGESIZE = number of rows to return per page,
- PAGEINDEX = what page  to return

Comment: PAGEINDEX is the number of items that must be ignored like in SQLite or ? would you please explain it a bit better?

Comment: is it actually working ? i'm getting same result for every query?

Comment: Does the pageIndex count up 1 by 1 or does it increase by pageSize each time?

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is almost correct, the below works for me:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons 
WHERE name LIKE :param 
LIMIT :pageSize 
OFFSET :pageIndex * :pageSize
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET :offset")
List<Persons> getList(int offset);
```

I've called this something like this:

```
public void loadData(int page){
      List<Persons> list = AppDb.getAppDatabase(context).getDAO().getList((page - 1) * 20);
}
```

This way, when your page number increases the offset is automatically managed and loads 20 records per page. If you want to set the `page size` dynamic, you can simply pass the limit as parameter.